# Change .jar name in MacOS dock in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, macos, jar

When I run my .jar, it always shows the program name as "Package.Class" in my OSX dock. Package being the package the class is in, and class being the class.

How would I change that to something else?

I am using Eclipse

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to [turn your Java project into a MacOS bundle](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/03-JavaDeployment/JavaDeployment.html):

> If you add an appropriate icon, it shows the application icon in the Dock, clearly identifying your application. (Otherwise, a default Java coffee cup icon appears in the Dock.)

But for that you probably have to leave Eclipse/post-process your JAR.

Comment: Ah, okay :) Thanks I was just curious.